# How to update from Windows Phone 8 to Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: lumia, update, 8.1

Today I read news about a Windows Phone Update coming to Lumia mobiles: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/04/03/nokia_winphone_8_1_mobes/

I have Nokia Lumia 525. How do I update its OS from Windows Phone 8.0 to 8.1?

Answer (score 11):

Once the update becomes available, later this year, it will be pushed out as an update to your phone. Your phone automatically looks for updates once a week. If you know it is available, you can force the check in the phone settings.

Answer (score 11):

As with other updates, it will be delivered "over the coming months", with the [support lifecycle page](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=windows+phone&Filter=FilterNO) implying that it becomes a supported release as of 24th June 2014, until (at least) 11th July 2017. The distribution of these incremental updates may be controlled by the mobile operator or the phone manufacturer from which you purchased your phone, so actual dates may vary by phone.

It is possible to register to get [access to prerelease Windows Phone operating system updates](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/featured/devpreview) if you have a developer unlocked phone. [Windows Phone 8.1 is now available as preview for developers](http://blogs.windows.com/windows/b/buildingapps/archive/2014/04/14/windows-phone-8-1-now-available-on-windows-phone-preview-for-developers.aspx)

There are a few key items that you must understand before you install any prerelease version on your phone:

> - After you install a preview update, you may void any warranty from your mobile operator and OEM.
> - A preview update only includes the Microsoft portion of the update; mobile operator and OEM driver updates will be available when the official update for your phone is available.
> - You cannot revert or return to a prior operating system release version after you have updated your phone to a preview update. We will move you forward to a "released state," but we cannot take you back to a prior "released state."

Comment: Don't know if it qualifies as "developer unlocked phone" but if you just  enroll in the free [Developer Preview Program](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/10/14/introducing-windows-phone-preview-for-developers.aspx) you are already eligible to download the new bits sooner too.

Comment: @VitorCanova To participate, you need to meet one of the three conditions: your phone is ‘developer-unlocked,’ you are a registered Windows Phone Store developer, OR you are a registered Windows Phone App Studio developer.

Comment: Last time I looked, App Studio was free...

Answer (score 0):

You can check is Lumia Cyan update availability [Software Update for Nokia Lumia with Windows Phone 8](http://www.nokia.com/global/support/software-update/wp8-software-update/)