# How to update to Windows Phone 8.1 update 1?

Tags: 8.1-update-1

I've seen that some users have downloaded Update 1 (GDR 1) for Windows Phone 8.1. I have a Nokia Lumia 930.

How to I get Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1 on my Nokia Lumia 930?

Comment: Developers can get the update now, and everyone else in a couple of months (this is generally how the update process works on WP)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/3479/106

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Settings-> Phone Update and click 'Check for Updates'

If the update is not available for your device, then you can still get it via the Developer Preview, which is a completely free and official process.

To enroll in the Dev Preview do the following:

1) Sign up for the 'Windows App Studio': To do this, go to: http://appstudio.windows.com and sign in with your Microsoft Account (Hotmail, Outlook, Live, MSN). 
[image: App Studio]

2) Next download the [Preview For Developers App](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/preview-for-developers/178ac8a1-6519-4a0b-960c-038393741e96) on your device.

The device must be running at least Windows Phone 8 GDR2 (8.0.10327.77 or higher), which the Lumia 930 is running. You can check the Windows Phone version your handset is running in Settings->About.

3) On the app select "Enable Preview for Developers". After that you can uninstall the app, if you so desire.

4) Go to Settings -> Phone Update and click 'Check for Updates'

You will get the updates up to and including Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1, unless you use an HTC device, which currently cannot receive Update 1. (Sad for me and my HTC 8X)

[image: Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1]

To test if you have the update, try dragging a tile on top of another tile. It should create a folder.

Answer (score 0):

Update 1 (GDR1) is currently only available to phones that are enrolled on the [Developer Preview programme](http://dev.windows.com/en-us/develop/devpreview), by checking for updates